# How do I set a Java library's custom event listener in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have been working on an Android project in Kotlin and would like to use this UI library. However, it's written in Java (and so is the documentation), and I'm not sure how to implement the event listener for the buttons. This is how it's supposed to be done in Java:

```java
final CircleMenuView menu = (CircleMenuView) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
menu.setEventListener(new CircleMenuView.EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuOpenAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
        Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationStart");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could do the same in Kotlin? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just paste the code in Android Studio and it will suggest to you to convert it to Kotlin code

The same code in Kotlin will be like this

```kotlin
val menu = findViewById<CircleMenuView>(R.id.circle_menu)
menu.setEventListener(object : CircleMenuView.EventListener {
    override fun onMenuOpenAnimationStart(view : CircleMenuView) {
        Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationStart");
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! My Android Studio didn't suggest anything (not sure why), but this makes a lot of sense :D

Comment: You're welcome bro, maybe you need to update the IDE or check the settings

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this

```
    val menu = findViewById<CircleMenuView>(R.id.circle_menu)
    menu.setEventListener{view->
       //Listener code goes here
    }
```